# error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV" in Nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, hadoop-yarn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5xRF.png)

Error appear when in run: yarn dev / yarn build.

I run it successfully local, but when I uploaded it to run on the server, an error occurred. The error description appears too short, which makes me quite confused when looking for a fix.

I try upgrade/downgrade node version but not working.
Reboot not working too :D

What can I do to fix it?

Node: 16
Nuxt: 2.15

Comment: After a long search, I suddenly discovered the nuxt version in my package.json was running ^2.15. And when I ran yarn install on the server it installed version 2.17 . This is what caused the conflict and caused the error.

I set it to ~2.15, and this worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.